# I don't see why this string index is out of range in Python

Tags: python

I don't understand why this would be out of range.

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
'''Returns True if the number represented by the string s is divisible by 3, False otherwise.'''

    length = len(str(s))
    end = s[length-1]
    sum = 0

    for x in range (0, int(end)):
        sum = sum + int(s[x])

    return sum
```

If I entered "25" as the parameter, I would have figured that 'end' equaling length-1 would have stopped the index being out of range.

Any help?

Comment: edit you indentation

Comment: if `s = "25"` then `end = "5"` , `s[2]` is out of range

Comment: just aside: your comment `''Returns True if..."` does not match your implementation - at all

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it doesn't match the comment. I need to get this bit working before I do that.

Comment: Oh my God, yes. Thank you Hacketo. I'd gotten confused with my keywords. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

Your `end` is not the index of the last digit, it's the digit itself.  Probably you want

```
end = len(str)
```

By the way, if you want to iterate over each digit:

```
for digit in str:
    sum += int(digit)
```

And more pythonic:

```
return sum( int(digit) for digit in str )
```

Comment: Should be `end = len(s) - 1`.

Comment: Yep, I got confused with my keywords. Figured it out, but thanks for responding anyway. :)

Comment: @Cyphase: if used in a range, the last element of the range is excluded, so it should not: `list(range(len("abc"))) == [0, 1, 2]`

Comment: @xtofl, fair enough. That's more an issue of the semantics of a variable named `end` and the fact that the OP was using it to refer to the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docstring

```
'''Returns True if the number represented by the string s is divisible by 3, False otherwise.'''
```

I just want to deliver another approach to test divisibiliy using the [modulo operator `%`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    '''Returns True if the number represented by the string s is divisible by 3, False otherwise.'''
    try:
        integer = int(s)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        return True if integer % 3 == 0 else False


s = input('Please enter a number: ')
print(divisible_by_3(s))
```

Comment: I think the intention of OP is to do the "sum of digits is divisible by 3" trick.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot that trick. Never used any of those tricks for non-mental arithmetics...

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    '''Returns True if the number represented by the string s is divisible by 3, False otherwise.'''

    length = len(str(s))
    end = s[length-1]
```

Here you are indexing the `s` itself, not the string. A better way would be

```
    s_str = str(s)
    length = len(s_str)
    end = s_str[length-1]
```

provided you really need this `end`.

```
    for x in range (0, int(end)):
        sum = sum + int(s[x])
```

Here you should do

```
    for x in range(0, length):
        sum += int(s_str[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

`end` isn't `length-1`; it's `s[length-1]`, a.k.a. the last character of the string `s`. When you call the function with `'25'`, since there aren't 5 characters in the string, you get an `IndexError`. Also, there's no need to do `str(s)` since `s` is already a string.

By the way, to accomplish what you the docstring says, you need to check if the sum is evenly divisible by 3.

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    length = len(s)
    end = length-1
    sum = 0

    for x in range(end+1):
        sum += int(s[x])

    return sum % 3 == 0
```

This is a better way to do it:

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    for digit in s:
        sum += int(digit)

    return sum % 3 == 0
```

Even better:

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in s) % 3 == 0
```

And of course you could just do this:

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    return int(s) % 3 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def divisible_by_3(s):
    try:
        return int(s) % 3 == 0
    except:
        return False
```

A simple way to reach your function target can be like this.